# How to save a file without prompting the user for a name/path?

Tags: c#, winforms, file, io

I'm trying to open a stream to a file.

First I need to save a file to my desktop and then open a stream to that file.

This code works well (from my previous project) but in this case, I don't want to prompt the user to pick the save location or even the name of the file. Just save it and open the stream:

```
Stream myStream;
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
    {
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, myStream);
```

Here's my code for the newer project (the reason for this question):

```
namespace Tutomentor.Reporting
{
    public class StudentList
    {
        public void PrintStudentList(int gradeParaleloID)
        {
            StudentRepository repo = new StudentRepository();
            var students = repo.FindAllStudents()
                               .Where(s => s.IDGradeParalelo == gradeParaleloID);

            Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
            Stream stream;

            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
            document.Open();
            foreach (var student in students)
            {
                Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
                p.Content = student.Name;
                document.Add(p);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a Windows/console app? ASP.NET? Silverlight? The platform has certain implications on what you're allowed to do w/o prompting.

Comment: @bitxwise: This on a desktop application. A Windows Forms, but I DO NOT want to prompt them on anything.

Comment: @Sergio: if you don't want to prompt them, then why prompt them? Do you not know how to open a file without using the save file dialog?

Comment: @Jon: The entire point of the question is how to do this without a prompt. The code that DOES show a prompt is just there to show what I want to do more or less, but without prompting.

Comment: It seems to me that you either need a config file specifying a path or you need to obtain a talent for ESP...or just prompt the user for where they want it saved

Comment: @Sergio: ok, to answer my question, you don't know how to open files.

Comment: @John: If I knew I would be asking this question would I? :)

Comment: @Sergio: I apologize. It never crossed my mind that someone might not know how to open files, and then also admit that they couldn't figure out to search for "file open".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)` to get the desktop directory.

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory),
                               "MyFile.pdf");
using(var stream = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
{
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
}
```

Comment: I like that it's ok for you to hardcode "MyFile.pdf" ;) GG =) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

If this is a local (e.g. Windows/console) application just make the `stream` a `FileStream` to whatever path you want (check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) for info on how to get the desktop folder path). If the user running the application has write permitions to that file it will be created/saved there.

If this is a web (e.g. ASP.Net) application you won't be able to save the file directly in the client machine without prompting the user (for security reasons).

Answer (score 0):

```
// However you initialize your instance of StudentList
StudentList myStudentList = ...;

using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\myDoc.pdf")) {
    try {
        myStudentList.PrintStudentList(stream, gradeParaleloID);
    }
    finally {
        stream.Close();
    }
}
```

You should pass the stream into your method:

```
public void PrintStudentList(Stream stream, int gradeParaleloID) { ... }
```

**EDIT**

Even though I hard coded a path above, you shouldn't do that, use something like this to get the path to your desktop:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

Comment: This is a bad answer because there are proper API's to get the path. Don't hard code it.

Comment: @Samuel: Wow, dude. This is just an EXAMPLE and the OP doesn't want to prompt for the path...

Comment: @bitxwise, it's a bad EXAMPLE that encourages bad practices.  The OP doesn't want to prompt for the path, so it would be helpful to tell the OP the proper way to get the desktop path.

Comment: @Samuel: The question was HOW TO SAVE A FILE W/O PROMPTING, not how to get the path to the desktop. Sorry, but I think you're being a little too anal about it...the OP's code showed he got the stream from a dialog result so the answer to his question is more importantly to just use FileStream directly. How he gets the path to his desktop is another issue...

Comment: @bitxwise, even if the OP didn't specifically say "I need to save a file to my desktop", I would still think any answer that hard codes a path that shouldn't be hard-coded is wrong.  I understand you disagree with my opinion about the quality of your answer, but it won't change my opinion.

Comment: @bitxwise, besides, you should get another -1 for using `try`/`finally` inside a `using` which is unnecessary and you should get another -1 for calling `stream.Close()` inside a `using` which is totally unnecessary.  You should delete this answer, it's got a lot of bad recommendations in it.

Comment: @Samuel: Yeah, Dipose() should be closing the stream. You're right in that =)

Answer (score -1):

`Stream myStream = new FileStream(@"c:\Users\[user]\Desktop\myfile.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);`

Your FileMode may differ depending on what you're trying to do. Also I wouldn't advise actually using the Desktop for this, but that's what you asked for in the question. Preferably, look into [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: This is a bad answer because there are proper API's to get the path.  Don't hard code it.

Comment: The answer was to demonstrate how to create a file stream.